# Magento Service Unavailable Error message

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-503

In my Magento website, I have received this error message:

> 503 Service Unavailable

I am not able to access any PHP files.

Does anyone know what is a reason behind that?

Comment: you need put some extra info. OS, server, magento version, db, etc is not the same if you use debian nginx and postgresql or ubuntu apache mysql

Comment: A 503 is a server-side error, generated by either Nginx or Apache when trying to run PHP. Your hosting provider should be able to provide you a log with information about this particular 503. From there you can figure out what the root problem is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your magento root directory, there is file called  **maintenance.flag** remove it.
2. If you not found  **maintenance.flag** file then check it might be hidden.